# Confusion between GetElementPtr and C++ API

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

Looking at the documentation of `GetElementPtr`:

http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html

The examples rely on multiple indexes: the 1st for the struct member and the 2nd for the element in the array. This supposedly returns an offset from the base pointer

I'm trying to figure out what's the correct way to create a given `GetElementPtr` instruction with the C++ API. Unfortunately, there are several varieties of the `CreateXXXGEP` instruction, with a parameter "val" that I presume is one of the indices. No version of it seems to use two indices as in the documentation: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html

Even the `CreateStructGEP` uses a single idx parameter!

I want to do a very simple thing; I want to take a char buffer:

```
Value* vB = llvm::ConstantDataArray::GetString(...)
```

and use the pointer to the array to pass it to another function that expects `i8*`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the variants taking an array of Value *. Construct ConstantInts and put them in an std::vector and pass them in.